# C# use one textBox for multiple items

Tags: c#

i am currently making a huge save editor for a game. I have a listBox that loads the names of weapons you have in the game. Currently whenever i click on one of the weapons in the listBox, the textBox shows how much ammo/quantity there is for that current item.

Example: listBox1 SelectedIndex 0 shows up as the AK47 and SelectedIndex 1 shows up as CBW. When i select a weapon the ammo value goes into textBox1.
If i click on AK47 and change the ammo, then move onto the CBW and then back to the AK47, the ammo resets to what it previously was.

what i cant seem to figure out is how commit any changes that are in process that are currently being edited until i am ready to do a final save

Comment: please read your question out loud to yourself and ask if it can be asked more clearly. right now it is fairly confusing. simply bolding and capitalizing some text won't make it easier to understand. take 5 or 10 minutes to figure out what you want to say, add an example or two. Will save you a lot more time in the long run than trying to explain your question 4 or 5 times to different people.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing the commit / save section of your Editor? First of all, I suggest to create a copy of the file your are about to edit) and open it readable in your editor. Then - after maintaining your first change, write the text to the original file (open the file writeable!), recretae the copy of the file and re-read it again (readable) and so on and so on. To be on the safe side you can create two copies. The idea behind it is to have one instance of the file readable and be able to Dave changes to the writable second instance. Afterwards the readable instance has to be reread.
Might be a bit confusing, but afterall not more confusing than the question. ;-)

Comment: I believe i follow what you are saying. I could wrap this up and make like 100 textBoxes to load each and every piece of ammo separately for each weapon but it would be nice to select a weapon and use as little textBoxes as possible.

Comment: You don't Need 100 textboxes. You just go on as described by you: select an edit item in the fist box / drop down / whatever and by this reload the second box for editing.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by reloading the second box for editing? I can think of a few ways to do so. Im not quite sure that they will keep the changes i made until its time to save

Comment: Sorry for being not so clear on this Point: my idea was to create a copy of your file, which will then store your changes as soon as you select the next item for editing. After storing These changes, you will have to "reload" it for reading in order to Display your changes in the editing box. However, when you press "Save", this copy of the file has to overwrite / replace the original file.